# Store view per country

Tags: multistore

I currently have a website for Dutch clients. But now I'd like to have a separate website for customers from belgium. So if a customer from belgium visit the website the must see another page with different blocks specifically aimed at this target group.

Both sites have the same domain name.

How can I set this in magento.

Answer (score 1):

Make a second storeview and turn on `Add Storecodes to URL` under `General > Web` in `System > Configuration`.

[image]

This will add for example **/be/** or **/nl/** to the store URL.

Don't forget to forward URLs without the store code to the **/nl/** path so you don't loose pagerank on already indexed pages

Comment: `But this way creates a menu in the upper right where you can choose between the Netherlands and Belgium. What I want is that the customer can not choose but is transmitted directly to the website associated with the country` by Marchel

Comment: @marchel that would require a GeoIP plugin. You would still need the steup as above but then have a module that redirects based on the geo location of the IP. explaining how to build that goes way beyond scope

Comment: @Sander Thanks for your comment, I'm going to give it a try. I'll let you know if it's all worked out